# pull playlists/video from youtube by scraping or parsing the video id

Tags: parsing, youtube, automation, embed, screen-scraping

my job has a youtube channel were we put our tutorials on. However we want to also put the tutorials on our company website. I know we can use the embed and embed every single one, but we don't want to have to do that every time we make a video. Is there a way that when you create a video on youtube that another website can automatically pull that video onto our website?

Comment: You can embed a [playlist](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en)

Comment: thanks, but that just embeds 1 video with a "playlists" icon on the left where you can select and inside that iframe pick different videos. i need to place all videos on the page automatically.